# How do I match numbers and create 2-dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like so `[1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7]`

How can I turn it into a 2-dimensional array that's based on matching numbers before the decimal?

ex.`[[1.2, 1.3, 1.4], [2.2, 2.3], [3.0], [4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7]]`

Comment: You don't say if the original array is in order or not

Comment: Your array is sorted numerically. Is that guaranteed to be the case?

Comment: is your array allways with positives values >= 1 ?

Comment: Yes, it will always be sorted lowest to highest.

Comment: Can there be gaps in the data e.g. `[1.2, 4.1, 6.7]`?

Comment: can your array be == `[ -10.3, -6.2, -6.1, 0.5, 8.6, 8.7 ]` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do this, building an array using indexes based on the integer portion of each value:

```js
arr = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7];

let res = arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  i = Math.trunc(v) - 1;
  c[i] = c[i] || [];
  c[i].push(v);
  return c;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

If you could have values starting at 0, or gaps in the values, you can use a similar piece of code and then use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to just extract the filled in arrays:

```js
arr = [0.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 6.6, 8.7];

res = arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  i = Math.trunc(v);
  c[i] = c[i] || [];
  c[i].push(v);
  return c;
}, []);
res = Object.values(res)
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This seems to assume quite a bit, like no negative numbers, never 0.x, and no holes.

Comment: You could also sort the array first if necessary :)

Comment: @slappy agreed; it is answering the question based on the data OP provided. If that proves to be incorrect I will edit/delete

Comment: @KenYo this code doesn't rely on the array being sorted.

Comment: Keep in mind that this code will produce empty entries in the array, which are different than `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: @RoboRobok not sure which you're referring to?

Comment: Try removing all values between 1.X and 4.X and log your array in the console.

Comment: @RoboRobok in my second piece of code that gives `[
  [
    0.2
  ],
  [
    6.6
  ],
  [
    8.7
  ]
]` that's why I have the `Object.values()` call

Comment: Yes, I was talking about the first one.

Comment: @RoboRobok that's why I added the second piece of code. The first piece is indeed dependent on the numbers having no gaps.

Comment: I still can't get over these weird empty values in JS. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want empty arrays in between, you can use `reduce()` like this:

```js
const numbers = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7];

const grouped = numbers.reduce(
    (result, number) => {
        result[Math.trunc(number)].push(number);
        return result;
    },
    Array(Math.trunc(Math.max(...numbers)) + 1).fill().map(() => [])
);
```

Result:

```js
[
    [],
    [1.2,1.3,1.4],
    [2.2,2.3],
    [3],
    [4.3,4.4,4.5,4.6,4.7]
]
```

Comment: Worth noting that by doing `.fill([])`, you're sharing the same object (array) reference between every index. Doesn't matter because your `.cocnat()` creates new arrays, but just in case someone tries to mutate an empty array without overwriting with a new one.

Comment: I have edited it to use `map()` instead (preceded by `fill()`, because you can't map empty values). This way, I could simplify it to use `push()` instead of `concat()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's always sorted, you can use this imperative approach:

```js
const arr = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7];

let curr = -Infinity;
let currArr = null;
const res = [];

for (let n of arr) {
  if (Math.trunc(n) > curr) {
    res.push(currArr = [curr = n]);
  } else {
    currArr.push(n);
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

It just tracks the latest number, and its current sub-array. If the next integer is greater than the current number, it creates a new array, otherwise it pushes into the current sub-array.

Some may not like using the result of an assignment as a value. If not, it can easily be reworked with a couple extra lines of code.

Comment: Given the data is sorted, this is probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `sort`, then traverse using `forEach` and group based on `Math.floor` value.

```js
const split = (data) => {
  const output = [];
  let temp = [];
  data
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .forEach((num) => {
      const [first] = temp;
      if (first && Math.floor(num) > Math.floor(first)) {
        output.push([...temp]);
        temp = [];
      }
      temp.push(num);
    });
  if (temp.length > 0) {
    output.push([...temp]);
  }
  return output;
};

const data = [1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2.2, 2.3, 3.0, 4.3, 4.4, 4.5, 4.6, 4.7];

console.log(split(data));
```